# Nested vscode settings in a large project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here's my file structure:

- root

  - .vscode
  - templates

    - .vscode

I'd like the settings in the nested "templates" folder to apply only there, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to do this?